# App with iAd and App without ad should in different projects?

Tags: ios, browser, uialertview, iad, appstore-approval

here is my question, i made an app and put on appstore, but i wish to charge the version without any iAd for 69p ...and the version WITH iad built in for free...

so, should I make two separte projects for each version?
and how do i make the free version with iAd should a pop up alert recommend user to go to appstore buy the ad free version?
is it just a normal UIAlertView with delegate method to call the App Store or open it as UIWeb in browser? how do i implement that?

any suggestions ?thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use compiler flags to wrap around your code so that you can have one source, and create multiple targets from the same project and build multiple apps (with different app identifiers and everything).

However, this causes you do have to manage two different apps in the app store (entering the same meta data twice), and deal with the review process on two different apps.

Also, people might skip over your paid version, whereas they would have installed your free version, and upgraded later.

I recommend that you have one source, one project, one target, and one app in the app store and use in app purchases (IAP) to turn off advertisements.